# append file & directory to /

Tags: linux, scripting, command

if I have directory /test and create or copy subs directories and files , eg

```
root@box:/test/etc/config# ls
newfile1
newfile2
newfile3
newfolderz
newfoldery
```

how can be automatically appended to / with same path ?

```
root@box:/etc/config# ls
newfile1
newfile2
newfile3
newfolderz
newfofdery
existing_files1
existing_files2
existing_filesX
```

also if I remove it from /test will be removed  /

thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can use symlinks:

`ln -s /etc /test`

Which will make an link from /etc to /test, if you modify something in /test, it will be modified in /etc too.

You can use hardlinks for files:

`ln file testfile`

Like with symlinks, if you modify `testfile`, `file` will be modified too.

> also if I remove it from /test will be removed /

be careful while removing symlinks, don't do rm -r test/* because that will delete /etc. Instead use `unlink(1)`

`unlink /test`

Comment: Is it possible    ``` ln -s  /  /test ```

Comment: to add eg   /test/newfolder123     to  /newfolder123

Comment: no, instead just use cp -r /test/newfolder123 /